How to disable low-level key repeats
I noticed that many keys repeat on my debian system. I tested with xev and apparently even my SHIFT and CTRL keys repeat, i.e. I get a series of key press and key release events. If I hold the SHIFT key and press another letter key, I sometimes get a lowercase character. also in the ttys, keys repeat. I have two USB keyboards and keys repeat on both.
I tried xset and kbdrate with no effect.
This made me believe, it must be the kernel or the keyboard itself, that causes this. So I did a
sudo cat /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:7.4.4.2:1.0-event-kbd

and indeed, if I hold down a key I get an endless stream of wild characters.

Do USB keyboards do such things, and if so, how can I disable this?
Or is it more likely the kernel, and then what?
Or is there any other advice?

Edit:
To verify that the repeats originate from a very level far below X, I rebooted and entered the BIOS. There is one place where you can actually type something: the administrator password. And indeed, I get repeats even there. Also while still withing grub my keys repeat.
My keyboards are:

Hama KC-500 (main keyboard)
Easterntimes Tech I-500

I also have an Air Mouse with a keyboard. I don't get repeats there.
Edit2: I just connected the Eastern keyboard to my wive's Apple. No repeats there. Then connected it to my Linux box and still no repeats. Did the same with the Hama keyboard. Both keyboards work okay for now.

That certainly is not the way most USB keyboards work. Test it on another device to see if it repeats there. As to a remedy, you provide no information for your keyboard make and model, so don't expect an answer.
